# Determine if two total values from different surveys are significantly different

Tags: survey

I have the responses from two surveys, one from this year and one from last year. Respondents could select what kind of organization they belong to (e.g., Library). I have only been given the total tally from last year's survey (e.g., Library = 124) and the total number of respondents (e.g., n = 1603). How can I determine if the amount of respondents who belong to a library this year is significantly different from last year?

Comment: I hope the survey is clear what constitutes 'belonging' to a library. As a faculty member, I suppose I 'belong' to the University library. I visit the local city library from time to time, but do not have a library membership card.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are comparing two binomial proportions.  If two different (independent) random samples from the same population
were surveyed in the two years, then you can test whether the two sample
proportions are significantly different, indicating that the population proportion of library members has changed from last year to this year.

*Guessing* that this year's numbers might be 150 Librarians out of
1600 surveyed, the sample proportion of library members would have
increased from $\hat p_1 = 0.077$ to $\hat p_2 = 0.093,$ but that
would not be a statistically significant change at the 5% level because the resulting
P-value is $0.097 > 0.05.$

The output below is from Minitab software.
Most comprehensive statistical software programs will perform such a test of two
proportions, and the formula for the test statistic can be found
in most intermediate-level applied statistics texts. This test uses
a normal approximation to the difference in binomial sample proportions.

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample    X     N  Sample p
1       124  1603  0.077355
2       150  1600  0.093750

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  -0.0163950
95% CI for difference:  (-0.0357604, 0.00297036)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  
   Z = -1.66  P-Value = 0.097
```

Also notice that a 95% CI for the difference includes 0, which is
another way to say that my fake data for the current year do not show a significant change from your data.

This test is described in the [NIST Handbook](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section3/prc33.htm).

Another test you might use is called Fisher's Exact Test. It is based on
the hypergeometric distribution. Minitab's result from that test:

```
Fisher’s exact test: P-Value = 0.101
```

Comment: I understand we are comparing proportions but am unsure what exact test you are using (Not Fisher's test). Am I right to assume this is a two-tailed Z Score for population proportions?

Comment: I have made two changes in my answer: (1) I have slightly changed the hypothetical data to more closely match the sample size of your data. (2) I have included a link to the NIST website that explains the test for two proportions implemented in Minitab.